# evaluate variable/function in gdb

Tags: c++, c, gdb, mmap

I have the following code,

```
...
char* seg = mmap(0, ...)
printf("seg=%x\n", seg);
...
```

The program prints with `seg=b7ffd000`. While in gdb (for the same execution), when using `p/x seg`, it prints `$2 = 0x0`. I am confused here. Isn't it the same var `seg`? why are the values different.

PS: in `mmap`, the first argument is the preferably address of mapped memory and the return value is the actual address of mapped memory.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimisations enabled?

Comment: Yes, when with -O3 removed, the problem is gone. Interested in why. Like which value is the real address of memory, with optimization enabled...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that you've answered my question in the comments, I can answer!

The value that you see as the result of the `printf` is the real address.  You are seeing `0` as the value of `seg` in the debugger because when optimizations are enabled, the compiler is free to do all sorts of weird things (which generally makes step-by-step debugging tricky).  The "observable" behaviour should always be correct, though (assuming you're not relying on any undefined behaviour).