# memory copy from void*

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I have following code,

```
char * segbase_char = (char*)segbase;
```

As debugged in gdb, it prints

```
segbase_char = 0x80e2da8
segbase = 0xb7ffd000
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong ... or doing one thing and expecting another. What type is `segbase`? How are you printing values in gdb? ...

Comment: mmm reading better, I think you need to provide more info. like, a working minimal example, or the gdb steps taken

Comment: The answer to this will be identical to that of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823843/evaluate-variable-function-in-gdb/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible that optimisation has resulted in code being moved around, such that the load of `segbase_char` has been delayed.  Try compiling with a lower level of optimisation enabled.

Comment: How should I disable optimization... Previously, I have no -O enabled in compilation, though.

Comment: @Richard: Use -00 (big O and a zero) as compilerflag, because it is possible that the compiler has optimization turned on as a default